# Can't figure out where this syntax error is

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[ jQuery(".track").hide();jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery(".track").show();});]]></script>
```

Console says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

What is the issue with the syntax? I don't see it.
I'm assuming it really means everything inside the `<script>` tags, since it starts off with a `<`

Not sure how to get to this file to fix, I'm thinking something/plugin is injecting this, but how do I find out what is causing it?

Is there any easier fix?

Thanks

Comment: learn to indent your code

Comment: `<![CDATA[` is not needed in HTML5. which your doctype is. p.s. Good music.

Comment: @LeleDumbo What do you mean? This is all generated through wordpress and plugins.

Comment: @Victory You like the music? It's a friends band, thought I would help them out and build them a site. I'll let em know.

Comment: Yes, its good. The plugin is putting invalid code. Or its getting edited by something else after the fact, which plugin is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would fix the error if for some reason you insist on using CDATA, but again its not needed because the page is very HTML5

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 
jQuery(".track").hide();jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery(".track").show();});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect, I found the plugin that was doing it. Thanks for the fix! I'll accept as soon as I can

Comment: `CDATA` blocks are necessary in XHTML/XML documents, it is not necessary in any HTML version.